# Should I use Ground State-Ground State (GS-GS) $Q$-value for decay heat?

Tags: thermodynamics, nuclear-physics, radiation, half-life

I am calculating the decay heat of sample of an isotope of plutonium at a single point in time. To do so, I am using the formula

$$Q = λNE,$$

where $Q$ is the decay heat for a given sample of plutonium, $λ$ is the decay constant, $N$ is the number of atoms in the sample, and $E$ is the heat for a single decay. For the value of $E$, should I use the Ground State-Ground State (GS-GS) $Q$-value for the given decay, located in the [NNDC](https://www.nndc.bnl.gov/)? Or is there another value I should be using?

I ask this because for the Pu241 isotope, [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plutonium#Decay_heat_and_fission_properties) table shows the decay heat to be 4.2 watts per gram, which is not in agreement with the GS-GS $Q$-value of PU241 (20.78 keV), but is in agreement with the energy of the beta-decay (5.23 keV).

If the GS-GS value isn't used, why?

Answer (score 0):

The decay heat corresponds to the energy of the particle released during the decay of the parent nucleus. A nucleus in its ground state does not release any energy before a possible future decay.

241Pu decays almost exclusively by beta decay, i.e. an electron is released into the environment. So the energy to consider ($E$) is the beta kinetic energy (5.23 keV).